# How can I detect a Vue $router.back() is done, rather than the case of empty history stack?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, html5-history

I'm using Vue with VueRouter.

And there is a back button on my page, I'm now setting the `@click` action to do `$router.back()`.

```
<a class="btn-back" @click="$outer.back()"></a>
```

But if the page is opened directly (without a previous history url), nothing happend.

In this case, I want the page replace to a specific location (home page for example). How can I do that?

I've been looked for the techique to tell if the history is empty with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a tricky way to do this.

Actually, if there is some other previous page in the history stack, after we call `$router.back()`, the route info should have been changed.

So, we can check the route and tell if the route is changed, after `$router.back`. If the route is not changed, it means the history stack is empty, then we do the `$router.replace()` instead.

Overall, I wrote such a method:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    backOrRedirect (route) {
      const vm = this
      const originRoute = { ...vm.$route }
      vm.$router.back()
      // Of course, we must detect until a $nextTick is reached
      vm.$nextTick(() => {
        // If the route is not changed, we do the redirect
        if (_.isEqual(originRoute, vm.$route)) {
          // Redirect to the home path by default
          vm.$router.replace(route || '/')
        }
      })
    }
  }
  // ,,,
}
```

> I use lodash to compare between the origin route and the newRoute object.

So, we can easily call `vm.backOrRedirect(url)` to launch a `$router.back()`, which will definitely fall back to redirect to some page when the history stack is empty.